# How to solve a matrix reachability recursion problem efficiently?

Tags: algorithm

I have just appeared in an interview where this question was asked.

The problem is:

I have a matrix as follows:

```
3 3
0 1 -1
1 0 -1
1 1 1
```

The first line contains `row numbers (n)` and `column numbers (m)`. Then the following is the given matrix, where `1` means gold piece and `-1` means obstacle.

**Rules**:

- I have to go from `(0, 0)` to `(n-1, m-1)` and then from `(n-1, m-1)` to `(0, 0)` back.
- I can move only to `right` and `down` while going from `(0, 0)` to `(n-1, m-1)` and only `left` and `up` while coming back from `(n-1, m-1)` to `(0, 0)`.
- During the above travels, if I encounter a `1`, then I pick up that gold piece. Similarly, while coming back if I encounter a `1` on the path I pick up that `1`.
- If at `(n-1, m-1)` value is `-1` or no path to `(n-1, m-1)` exists then overall gold pieces count is 0.

**Problem** is to find the maximum number of gold pieces that can be accumulated.

**My approach**:

During the time of the interview, I deduced that the rules infer that if we merge both the rules for `(0, 0)` to `(n-1, m-1)` and from `(n-1, m-1)` to `(0, 0)` , we will essentially want to reach `(0, 0)` to `(n-1, m-1)` with all possible directions: up, right, down, and left. All I have to do is count the maximum number of 1 while using these 4 path directions.

Then I came up with the following recursive code which does not seem efficient but works.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int n, m;
int mat[100][100];
int lookup[100][100];

int getcount(int pgc, int r, int c) {
    if(r == n-1 && c == m-1) {
        if(mat[r][c] == -1) return 0;
        else return mat[r][c] + pgc;
    }

    int cgc = mat[r][c];
    int tmp1 = 0, tmp2 = 0, tmp3 = 0, tmp4 = 0;

    if (((r + 1) < n) &&( mat[r + 1][c] != -1) && (lookup[r+1][c] != -1)) {
        // go down
        lookup[r + 1][c] = -1;
        tmp1 = getcount(cgc + pgc, r + 1, c);
        lookup[r + 1][c] = 0;
    }

    if (c + 1 < m && mat[r][c + 1] != -1 && lookup[r][c+1] != -1) {
        // go right
        lookup[r][c + 1] = -1;
        tmp2 = getcount(cgc + pgc, r, c + 1);
        lookup[r][c + 1] = 0;
    }
    if (r - 1 >= 0 && mat[r - 1][c] != -1 && lookup[r - 1][c] != -1) {
        // go up
        lookup[r - 1][c] = -1;
        tmp3 = getcount(cgc + pgc, r - 1, c);
        lookup[r - 1][c] = 0;
    }
    if (c - 1 >= 0 && mat[r][c - 1] != -1 && lookup[r][c-1] != -1) {
        // go left
        lookup[r][c - 1] = -1;
        tmp4 = getcount(cgc + pgc, r, c - 1);
        lookup[r][c - 1] = 0;
    }

    return max(tmp1, max(tmp2, max(tmp3, tmp4)));
}

int collectMax() {
    int ans = 0;
    if(mat[n-1][m-1] == -1 || mat[0][0] == -1) ans = 0;
    else {
        int r = 0, c = 0;
        int gc = 0;
        // if(mat[0][0] == 1) gc = 1;
        ans = getcount(gc, r, c);
        ans = max(0, ans);
    } 
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    cin>>n>>m;

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<m; j++) {
            cin>>mat[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout<<collectMax()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How to make it efficient? Is there a scope of using DP to optimise?

Some sample test cases for practice:

**Input1:**

```
3 3
0 1 -1
1 0 -1
1 1 1
```

**Output1:**

```
5
```

**Input2:**

```
3 3
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

**Output2:**

```
7
```

**Input3:**

```
3 3
0 1 1
1 0 -1
1 1 -1
```

**Output3:**

```
0
```

Comment: What result would your algorithm give for `[[1 1 1][1 -1 -1][1 1 1]]`?

Comment: My current which I have mentioned in my questions gives me 7 for the input `[[1 1 1][1 -1 -1][1 1 1]]`

Comment: Got it. The correct answer should have been 5 not 7.

Comment: @ScottHunter: Please suggest a better and correct algorithm. I don't care about my interview. I want to learn how to solve problems.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-points-top-left-matrix-bottom-right-return-back/amp/

Answer (score 3):

This has a solution in *O*(min(*m*<sup>2</sup>*n*, *mn*<sup>2</sup>)) time and *O*(min(*m*<sup>2</sup>, *n*<sup>2</sup>)) space using dynamic programming.

The idea is to consider angled "strips" that look like this (in bold):

> `0 1 -1`
>   `1 0 -1`
>   `1 1  1`

Your character (= "you", but I want to distinguish between what your *program* will do in *finding* the best path and what your *character* will do in *taking* the best path) will visit each such strip exactly twice: once on the way from (0, 0) to (*m*−1, *n*−1), and once on the way back. This is because each legal move moves from one strip to the adjacent strip in the allowed direction.

So, for each strip, starting with the single-element strip at (0, 0) and ending with the single-element strip at (*m*−1, *n*−1), your program will consider all possible pairs of elements in that strip — call them (*i*<sub>1</sub>, *j*<sub>1</sub>) and (*i*<sub>2</sub>, *j*<sub>2</sub>) — and find the maximum number of distinct gold coins that can be obtained on the path from (0, 0) to (*i*<sub>1</sub>, *j*<sub>1</sub>) plus the path from (*i*<sub>2</sub>, *j*<sub>2</sub>) back to (0, 0). For each strip, store the results in a matrix so that it can be used in computing the results for the next strip. (After you've finished a strip, you can discard the results from its previous strip.)

Special cases:

- Make sure to support "degenerate" pairs where both elements are the same, that is, where *i*<sub>1</sub> = *i*<sub>2</sub>. For such pairs, if the element contains a gold coin, make sure to count it only *once*.
- Make sure to distinguish an *impossible* partial path (where either (*i*<sub>1</sub>, *j*<sub>1</sub>) or (*i*<sub>2</sub>, *j*<sub>2</sub>) is an obstacle, or can only be reached via an obstacle) from a partial path that simply doesn't contain any coins. Otherwise you'll mis-process cases like this:

  ```
  0  0 -1
  0 -1  1
  0  0  0
  ```

  where the correct answer is 0 because the lone gold coin is not actually reachable.